# Utilizing "Send Money to Friends and Family" functionality via our app

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Our app needs to utilize the functionality "send money to friends and family".

Now we can perform PERSONAL payments using AdaptivePayments without any fee (as expected) but this type of transaction seems to be purchasing transaction rather than "send money to family and friends" transaction. Looking at the payment details instead of seeing the information which is related to "send money to friends and family" type of transfers we see the following details: "Payment/Payment received" instead of "Money sent/received", "Seller info", "Your purchase", "Item amount", "Shipping", "Tax", "Purchase total". Below you will find request details:

```
curl -s --insecure \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: $USERID" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: $PASSWORD" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: $SIGNATURE" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: $APPID" \
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US\
&actionType=PAY\
&sender.email=$SENDER\
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=$RECEIVER\
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=$AMOUNT\
&receiverList.receiver(0).paymentType=PERSONAL\
&feesPayer=SENDER\
&currencyCode=USD\
&memo=Simple payment example.\
&cancelUrl=$CANCELURL\
&returnUrl=$RETURNURL"
```

Looking at the [PayPal app settings](https://monosnap.com/file/4YVXu5XfYgyW6DdU95sITGLJB2Jkgh) the option "Send money" is deprecated and REST API should be used instead. But all these payments using REST API are performed between seller and buyer. What do we need to change in the request mentioned above so we can be able to utilize functionality "send money to friends and family" via our app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?