# Sending money from card to family/friends using PayPal API

Tags: python, rest, paypal

I have searched for StackOverflow and PayPal documentation and I am unable to find an answer for my query. I apologize in advance if this has been asked, I am new to programming.

Use case: Using a script, I would like to send money from a card that is linked to my PayPal account to a friend that holds a valid PayPal account. This is done on a frequent basis, at least once a month, so I am looking to create a Python script or similar that will allow me to complete the task without logging into PayPal/confirming any extra steps. I realize the security implications of such a script and will take appropriate measures to secure it.

My search results have led me here:
[How to send money to any paypal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/how-to-send-money-to-any-paypal-account) and here [Utilizing "Send Money to Friends and Family" functionality via our app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268506/utilizing-send-money-to-friends-and-family-functionality-via-our-app)
and subsequently here:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

However, these results and documentation does not seem to provide insight into how I can program the "Send money to friends/family" feature.

My question is: Is it possible to create a script which functions as mentioned?

Comment: Going by the Adaptive Payments API for a Simple Payment you just use the /Pay endpoint using either NVM or JSON https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCallsHeadersAndPaymentTypes/

Comment: It appears that I need to authorize once more on PayPal after the initial PayRequest, how can I make it completely automated? Also, I have multiple cards on my personal PayPal account, how I can specify the card if it is not a preferred payment method?

Comment: Came to the same problem: The AdaptivePayments API is now deprecated. But with the REST-API it is NOT possible to do any kind of freinds/family payment. I just opened a case on paypale technical support and ask for a solution.

Comment: @RobinKluth did you find a solution and could you share it? I run into the same problem

Comment: @fsulser No - The REST-API is not able to do this.